# Finding the limit of an exponential term minus a polynomial term

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Find the limit for
>   $$\lim_{x\to +\infty} e^x - x^2$$

The result should be $+\infty$. How do you do it?

If you convert the equation to a quotient:

$$\frac{1-e^{-x}x^2}{e^{-x}}$$

and apply L'Hopital's rule, I got $-\infty$, which is wrong.

Comment: Maybe rewrite as $e^x\left(1-\frac{x^2}{e^x}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} e^x - x^2=\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2 \left(\frac{e^x}{x^2}-1\right)=\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{ \log\left(x^2(e^x/x^2-1)\right)}=\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{2\log x+\log{(e^x/x^2-1)}} = \lim_{x\to \infty}e^{2\log x}\cdot\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{\log{(e^x/x^2-1)}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{2\log x}\cdot\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{\log{(e^x/x^2)}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{2\log x +x -2\log x}=\\\lim_{x\to \infty}e^x= +\infty.$$